# Can't get 360 mp4 video to play in VR (Oculus GO) in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, 360-virtual-reality, oculusgo

I am trying to create an Oculus GO app that requires the feature to play mp4 videos in 360 with sound. I have followed countless of tutorials both on text from Googling and from YouTube and all result in the same output. I end up being able to hear the sound from the video but I can only see the camera background (which is black/brownish in my case). I have absolutely no idea of what to do and there is nothing on the internet (that i have been able to find) that can help me

My scene consists of the following:
- A OVRPlayerController containing a OVRCameraRig
- A videoplayer

I have attached a picture giving you an overview of my entire project and everything at play in this scene at this link --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLxoN.jpg

Please, I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you playing the video in a sphere? Try to change the texture. The video is playing since you can hear the audio, its the texture problem. Create a material and switch between UI and other shaders.

Comment: I actually haven't tried that. I was under the impression that using a skybox would be more efficient but of course if it's not working I might as well try the sphere thing. The differences can't be that great. Thanks! I'll provide an update